# Why can't I run the azure movie recommendation example?

Tags: powershell, azure, recommendation-engine

I am new to MS Azure.

I have a question about running the movie recommendation example.
I have already installed the powershell, my version of hdInsight is 3.1, and I have followed [the tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-mahout/). 
But I can't do the following code:

```
# Create the job definition
$jobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition `
  -JarFile $jarFile `
  -ClassName "org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob" `
  -Arguments $jobArguments
```

The error is about the Jarfile.

Here is the error:

```
New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition : 無法將 'System.Object[]' 轉換為 'JarFile' 參數所需的 'System.String' 型別。不支援指定的方法。
位於 線路:2 字元:12
+   -JarFile $jarFile `
+            ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition]，ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.PSCmdlets.NewAzureHDIn 
   sightMapReduceDefinitionCmdlet
```

Does anyone have idea about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

what it looks like has happened is that the version of Mahout on the cluster has recently been updated, so the hard-coded path in the example code is now wrong.

To fix this, change the line in the PowerShell script that reads:

`$jarFile = "file:///c:/apps/dist/mahout-0.9.0.2.1.3.0-1887/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.9.0.2.1.3.0-1887-job.jar"`

to

`$jarFile = "file:///c:/apps/dist/mahout-0.9.0.2.1.6.0-2103/examples/target/mahout-examples-0.9.0.2.1.6.0-2103-job.jar"`

That's the path from a cluster I provisioned today. If you have an cluster you provisioned a while back, you can enable remote desktop and connect to the cluster, then go to c:\apps\dist\ to see the current version of Mahout.

EDIT: here's a modified script that will dynamically grab the mahout jar name using Hive.

```
# The HDInsight cluster name.
$clusterName = "the cluster name"

# NOTE: The version number portion of the file path
# may change in future versions of HDInsight.
# So dynamically grab it using Hive.
$mahoutPath = Invoke-Hive -Query '!${env:COMSPEC} /c dir /b /s ${env:MAHOUT_HOME}\examples\target\*-job.jar' | where {$_.startswith("C:\apps\dist")}
$jarFile = "file:///$mahoutPath"
#
# If you are using an earlier version of HDInsight,
# set $jarFile to the jar file you
# uploaded.
# For example,
# $jarFile = "wasb:///example/jars/mahout-core-0.9-job.jar"

# The arguments for this job
# * input - the path to the data uploaded to HDInsight
# * output - the path to store output data
# * tempDir - the directory for temp files
$jobArguments = "-s", "SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE",
                "--input", "wasb:///example/data/u.data",
                "--output", "wasb:///example/out",
                "--tempDir", "wasb:///temp/mahout"

# Create the job definition
$jobDefinition = New-AzureHDInsightMapReduceJobDefinition `
  -JarFile $jarFile `
  -ClassName "org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob" `
  -Arguments $jobArguments

# Start the job
$job = Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clusterName -JobDefinition $jobDefinition

# Wait on the job to complete
Write-Host "Wait for the job to complete ..." -ForegroundColor Green
Wait-AzureHDInsightJob -Job $job

# Write out any error information
Write-Host "STDERR"
Get-AzureHDInsightJobOutput -Cluster $clusterName -JobId $job.JobId -StandardError
```

Comment: @Larry Franks Could you please check.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454864/error-in-running-movie-recommendations-by-using-apache-mahout-with-hdinsight  Thanks..